# Is it true identification with mathematically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

**EDİTED**

Is it true identification with mathematically?

> $$\sum_{i = 1\\j=2}^{k+1\\\,\,\,k} n_i^2 +{p_j}^2=n_1^2+p_2^2+n_2^2+p_3^2+...+n_k^2+p_{k+1}^2$$

Is it true identification

Comment: I think what you've written isn't commonly accepted notation. I would interpret it as: $\sum^k_{i=1} \sum^{k+1}_{j=2}$. On the other hand, it looks like you meant something different? Would you mind giving some context of where this comes from?

Comment: That makes more sense than your previous attempt, but you are still not telling us everything. What are the $n_i$ and $p_j$? And could you please clarify the notation of your sum (if you have two indices, it's better to write two sum symbols : right now, it's not obvious wether $i$ or $j$ is supposed to go to $k$ or $k+1$).

Comment: İ didnt understood $=2$?

Comment: The first time you posted this question it was closed because it didn't make sense.  It still doesn't make sense.  What it mean to have $k+1$ hovering over the $k$?

Comment: @Newstudent I edited my comment - typo in the formula. In addition, I'd like to point out that the linear terms go missing on the RHS?

Comment: Ok, a little more clear. Do you mean to say that $$\sum_{i = 1\\j=2}^{k+1\\\,\,\,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=2}^{k+1}$$?

Comment: @Bacon ohh,Thank you so much You understood my problem. yes you are true absolutely.

Comment: @Shuri2060 yes, but your formula doesnt equal my formula..Because your formula double summation.

Comment: @Newstudent When you say 'my formula' what exactly do you mean? Where did you get this notation from - because it isn't standard. You should write what windircurse posted if that's what your intention is.

Comment: @Shuri2060 hmm...you say this is not true notation?

Comment: Yes - $\sum_{i=1}^k(n_i^2+p_{i+1}^2)$, as windircurse suggested would be what you'd write. You should only have one index for each summation.

Comment: @Shuri2060  I wanted to know that, is it true or not? And you say this is not true notation. İ understood.

Comment: What are you referring by 'it' in 'is it true or not'?

Comment: @Shuri2060 sorry, my english very bad. ı wanted say that my "notation" .double index

Comment: The phrase 'true notation' doesn't make any sense. Your notation is incorrect, however.

Comment: Ohh, sorru my english so bad. İ wanted say that, my notation  "correct" or incorrect notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use
$$\sum_{i=1}^k(n_i^2+p_{i+1}^2)$$

Comment: I wrote example. İ know that is true spelling?

Comment: Comment and not answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/837285)

Comment: @jvdhooft Yet it is the accepted answer....